# Synonym of 'election' with less political meaning

Tags: word-usage

I will give some details regarding how I am going to use it. It has to go along good with the word 'room'. Consider a game where players (in a special room) vote upon a list of activities which they will do next. (activities are suggested and voted on by the players). 'Election room' or 'Vote room' remind me (and the people who have tested it with these names) too much of politics in real world.

Basically what I am looking for is something with as little message other than 'you choose' as possible.

Cheers

Comment: A *decision* room?

Comment: Hm... maybe. My plan is to wait a while and see different suggestions. I am by all means not in a rush. It will also give me some time to do some research of my own.

Comment: Suffrage chamber.

Comment: Don't forget [consensus](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/consensus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are searching less political word for this situation, then the  ***"Poll"*** is perfect for you.

**choice**

> An act of selecting or making a decision when faced with two or more possibilities.

**selection**

> The action or fact of carefully choosing someone or something as being the best or most suitable.

**option**

> A thing that is or may be chosen.

**pick**

> An act or the right of selecting something from among a group of alternatives.

**poll**

> The process of voting in an election: "the country went to the polls on March 10".

Comment: Detailed and on the spot answer. I was thinking of waiting more but this covers my question quite nicely.